# Laravel multiple sync

Tags: laravel

In my project ı have three tables for eloquent but i cant figure out how to connect each other.

First table : Cars 
Second Table : Car Property Category
Third Table : Car Properties

Mechanism is that,

Car property categories has many car properties. There is no problem in here.

But Car table has car property category and car properties. So when i try to eloquent with Car property category and properties i got sync error.

I tried with many to many but cant success full.

I created another table for car_id, car_property_category_id and property_id.
But in view side there on form submit, car property category and properties are going to controller as array. So i want to sync them as category and property. AS you can see below picture when property checked property category must add to table with property name

https://ibb.co/bvFw4zC

My codes are below;

Car Model:

```
public function properties()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(CarProperty::class,'car_car_properties');
}
```

Car Property Model

```
   public function category()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CarPropertyCategory','category_id','id');
    }

   public function car()
    {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class, 'car_car_properties');
    }
```

Car Property Category Model

```
 public function ozellikleri(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\CarProperty','category_id','id');
    }
```

My Blade File

```
@if($propertycategories->count())
                        @foreach($propertycategoriesas $category)
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">{{$category->name}}</label>
                            <div class="row">
                                <input type="hidden" name="categoryname[]" value="{{$category->id}}">
@foreach($category->properties as $property)

                                <div class="col-md-2 mg-t-20 mg-lg-t-0">
                                    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">

                                        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="property{{$property->id}}" name="properties[]" value="{{$property->id}}">
                                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="property{{$property->id}}">{{$property->name}}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                               @endforeach
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        @endforeach
                        @endif
```

Controller side Sync Codes

```
$properties = $request->input('properties ');
        $categories= $request->input('categories');

        $car = Car::find($id);

        $car->properties()->sync([$properties,$categories]);
```

My pivot table has 3 columns like below;

```
car_id car_property_id car_property_category_id
```

But i cant sync categories in this table. Only car_id and property_id can sync

I want that all categories and properties must sync same time.

NOT: I figured it out with array save

If somone needs codes below;

i figured it out. İf some needs;

```
       $data = [];
       foreach($request->properties as $property){
        $add = [];
        $find= CarProperty::where('id',$property)->first();
        $add ['car_property_id'] = $find->id;
        $add ['car_property_Category_id'] = $find->category->id;


        $data[] = $add ;




        }


        $arac->properties()->sync($data );
```

Comment: Please show the code defining the eloquent relationships, the code where you do the 'sync' and the error message.

Comment: question updated added codes

Comment: i figured it out. İf some needs;

           $data = [];
           foreach($request->properties as $property){
            $add = [];
            $find= CarProperty::where('id',$property)->first();
            $add ['car_property_id'] = $find->id;
            $add ['car_property_Category_id'] = $find->category->id;


            $data[] = $add ;




            }


            $arac->properties()->sync($data );

Comment: Great! I copied your solution into an answer. Please mark it as accepted so other people see that this question has been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
$data = []; 

foreach($request->properties as $property) { 
    $add = [];

    $find = CarProperty::where('id', $property)->first();

    $add['car_property_id'] = $find->id; 
    $add['car_property_Category_id'] = $find->category->id; 

    $data[] = $add ; 
} 

$arac->properties()->sync($data);
```